# Can "... sich den Blicken der anderen zu entziehen" be rewritten as "... sich den Blicken anderer zu entziehen"?

Tags: sentence-structure, article, genitive

Can

> Er versuchte, sich den Blicken *der anderen* zu entziehen.

be rewritten as

> Er versuchte, sich den Blicken *anderer* zu entziehen.

I seem to remember seeing an example where the article was omitted, but I'm not sure. Is there a particular grammatical rule governing this question?

Comment: For future reference, it helps to keep the entire question, including the title, in one language (quotes excluded). Use German or English, whichever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: To me, "der anderen" is more specific than "anderer". IMHO "der anderen" refers to some others mentioned before, "anderer" is more general and refers to any or all others that may exist. It depends on the context if the second form makes sense.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences have a different meaning, so one cannot be rewritten as the other.

In

> Er versuchte, sich den Blicken der anderen zu entziehen.

there's a specific group of "others" or "*the* others". In contrast, in

> Er versuchte, sich den Blicken anderer zu entziehen.

you're talking about "others" more in general. You're not specifying further who those "others" are.

You can express the difference quite literally in English:

> He tried to hide from the other's glances.
> He tried to hide from the other people's glances.

in contrast with

> He tried to hide from other's glances.
> He tried to hide from other people's glances.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. There should be a "yes, this is totally valid" and probably an explanation about the rules, why this is possible. Your answer just states the difference in meaning (and answer the question implicitely by reusing the example)

Comment: @Tode I didn't think it was necessary to spell out that if the sentences have different meanings, they can't substitute for each other, but oh well ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

While omitting the article seems fine, in the second example a noun seems missing (e. g. *anderer Spieler*). This might have been provided by an earlier sentence, but without context the sentence seems incomplete.

> Er nahm keine Rücksicht auf Andere.

would be such an example, where the article can be dropped. (Note, that *Andere* becomes a noun here.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: Somehow that example seems even more incomplete, though. :-)

Comment: I disagree with the claim that a noun was missing. The sentence is idiomatic, even without mentioning of a noun in a previous sentence. Moreover, in the example *andere* is an indefinite pronoun, which must not be capitalized.

Comment: I have to agree with DonHolgo and Björn... Your example is in no way a complete sentence and in the second example of op nothing is missing at all. sorry, downvote from me...

Comment: @guidot You just forgot the verb, you probably wanted to write _Er nahm keine Rücksicht auf Andere_